# Using R to plot correlation between two timeseries data

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, r-corrplot

I am trying to plot the correlation between dependent variables of two time series.

```
Data 1
======
1    3.1
2    3.3
3    3.1
4    4.5
...
...

Data 2
========
1    3.1
2    0.3
3    4.1
4    3.2
...
...
```

I am using R.

```
library(corrplot)
foo <- read.table("D:\\datas\\res\\A.txt", header=T,sep=",")
attach(foo)
foo1 <- read.table("D:\\datas\\res\\M.txt", header=T,sep=",")
attach(foo1)
res<-cor(foo$col1, foo1$col2)
corrplot(res, type="upper", order="hclust",     tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

Getting error:

> Error in corrplot(cor(foo$col1, foo1$col2), type = "upper", order = "hclust",  : 
>   Need a matrix or data frame!

I see only two values in 'z'. How can I convert this from vector form to matrix form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a data frame:

```
data_sel <-data.frame(foo$col1, foo1$col2)
res <- cor(data_sel)
corrplot(res, type="upper", order="hclust", tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

([and try to prevent using attach!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead))

Answer (score 2):

`corrplot` is a correlation matrix, i.e. the pairwise correlations between the variables denoted by the columns and rows. You only have one correlation value, <s>therefore you can't really plot it like that</s> (see edit).

EDIT:

Yeah, you can actually plot it, but it's useless, as you know beforehand there's only one useful value in the matrix;