# When to use 'with' function and why is it good?

Tags: r, syntax, keyword

What are the benefits of using `with()`? In the help file it mentions it evaluates the expression in an environment it creates from the data. What are the benefits of this? Is it faster to create an environment and evaluate it in there as opposed to just evaluating it in the global environment? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Mostly to save keystrokes when you have a long array name. But this is off-topic because many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I was wondering that too, in the examples though they have this `library(MASS)
with(anorexia, {
    anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
                    family = gaussian)
    summary(anorex.1)
})` which uses a lot more keystrokes to include the with statement.

Comment: This might be a good topic for the [R-Public chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public).

Comment: @PierreLafortune Sure, I can do that. Should I remove the question?

Comment: Don't delete. The community will decide through votes and participation.

Comment: where did you find that example?  The version in the main `?glm` page doesn't use `with()` (at least not in my version of R ...)  I agree it's not worth it in that case.

Comment: @BenBolker that was copied from the help files of with()

Comment: It's a good and worthwhile question which most R learners will eventually encounter, so let's all come up with a non-subjectie wording and keep it open.

Comment: It's a silly example.  Maybe I'll try to get it changed to something better.

Comment: ... the example I just suggested at r-devel@r-project.org was `with(mtcars,mpg[cyl==8 & disp>350])`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### `with` is a wrapper for functions with no `data` argument

There are many functions that work on data frames and take a `data` argument so that you don't need to retype the name of the data frame every time you reference a column. For example, `lm`, `plot.formula`, `subset`, `transform`, and the main `dplyr` functions like `mutate` and `summarize`.

`with` is a general purpose *wrapper* to let you use any function as if it had a data argument, so that you can refer to columns without using `$`.

Using the `mtcars` data set, we could fit a model with or without using the data argument:

```
# this is obviously annoying
mod = lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl + mtcars$disp + mtcars$wt + mtcars$am)

# this is nicer
mod = lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + wt + am, data = mtcars)
```

However, if (for some strange reason) we wanted to find the `mean` of `cyl + disp + wt`, there is a problem because `mean` doesn't have a data argument like `lm` does. This is the issue that `with` addresses:

```
# without with(), we would be stuck here:
z = mean(mtcars$cyl + mtcars$disp + mtcars$wt)

# using with(), we can clean this up:
z = with(mtcars, mean(cyl + disp + wt))
```

Wrapping `foo()` in `with(data, foo(...))` lets us use any function `foo` *as if* it had a `data` argument - which is to say we can use unquoted column names, preventing repetitive `data_name$column_name` or `data_name[, "column_name"]`.

### When to use `with`

Use `with` whenever you like interactively (R console) and in R scripts to save typing and make your code clearer. The more frequently you would need to re-type your data frame name for a single command (and the longer your data frame name is!), the greater the benefit of using `with`.

Also note that `with` isn't limited to data frames. From `?with`:

> For the default `with` method this may be an environment, a list, a data frame, or an integer as in `sys.call`.

I don't often work with environments, but when I do I find `with` very handy.

#### When you need pieces of a result for one line only

As @Rich Scriven suggests in comments, `with` can be very useful when you need to use the results of something like `rle`. If you only need the results once, then his example  `with(rle(data), lengths[values > 1])` lets you use the `rle(data)` results anonymously.

### When to avoid `with`

#### When there *is* a `data` argument

Many functions that have a `data` argument use it for more than just easier syntax when you call it. Most modeling functions (like `lm`), and many others too (`ggplot`!) do a lot with the provided `data`. If you use `with` *instead* of a `data` argument, you'll limit the features available to you. **If there is a `data` argument, use the `data` argument, not `with`.**

#### Adding to the environment

In my example above, the result was assigned to the global environment (`bar = with(...)`). To make an assignment *inside* the list/environment/data, you can use `within`. (In the case of `data.frames`, `transform` is also good.)

#### In packages

Don't use `with` in R packages. There is a warning in `help(subset)` that could apply just about as well to `with`:

> **Warning** This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.

If you build an R package using `with`, when you check it you will probably get warnings or notes about using variables without a visible binding. This will make the package unacceptable by CRAN.

### Alternatives to `with`

#### Don't use `attach`

Many (mostly dated) R tutorials use `attach` to avoid re-typing data frame names by making columns accessible to the global environment. [`attach` is widely considered to be bad practice and should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067680/903061). One of the main dangers of attach is that data columns can become out of sync if they are modified individually. `with` avoids this pitfall because it is invoked one expression at a time. There are many, many questions on Stack Overflow where new users are following an old tutorial and run in to problems because of `attach`. The easy solution is always *don't use `attach`*.

#### Using `with` all the time seems too repetitive

If you are doing many steps of data manipulation, you may find yourself beginning every line of code with `with(my_data, ...`. You might think this repetition is almost as bad as not using `with`. Both the `data.table` and `dplyr` packages offer efficient data manipulation with non-repetitive syntax. I'd encourage you to learn to use one of them. Both have excellent documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: It's also super useful when working with `rle`.  You can access the values without having to assign the `rle`. Example: `with(rle(data),  lengths[values > 1])`.  I find it quite useful, anyhow.

Answer (score 10):

I use it when i don't want to keep typing `dataframe$`. For example

```
with(mtcars, plot(wt, qsec))
```

rather than

```
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$qsec)
```

The former looks up `wt` and `qsec` in the `mtcars` data.frame. Of course

```
plot(qsec~wt, data = mtcars)
```

is more appropriate for plot or other functions that take a `data=` argument.

Comment: To save typing you can also use `transform` and/or `within`

Comment: @Rentrop Can you please give us an example with `transform` and/or `within`?