# Calculating age per animal by subtracting years in R

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I am looking to calculate relative age of animals. I need to subtract sequentially each year from the next for each animal in my dataset. Because an animal can have multiple reproductive events in a year, I need the age for the remaining events in that year (i.e. all events after the first) to be the same as the initial calculation.

Update:

The dataset more resembles this:

```
  Year ID Age 

1 1975 6  -1   
2 1975 6  -1   
3 1976 6  -1   
4 1977 6  -1   
6 1975 9  -1   
8 1978 9  -1
```

And I need it to look like this

```
  Year ID Age 

1 1975 6  0   
2 1975 6  0   
3 1976 6  1   
4 1977 6  2   
6 1975 9  0   
8 1978 9  3
```

Apologies for the initial confusion, if I wasn't clear on what I needed to accomplish.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read about the [tag:split-apply-combine] paradigm. Whenever you have data with multiple rows for specific ID (i.e. long-form).

Comment: Will do, thank you for the help.

Comment: ..and look at the introductions for `dplyr` and/or `data.table` packages (and later on, `tidyverse`). This is one of the biggest paradigms in R. It's incredibly powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things done "by group" are usually easiest to do using `dplyr` or `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%               # group by ID
  mutate(Age = Year - min(Year)) # add new column
```

or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(your_data) # convert to data table

            # add new column         by group
your_data[, Age := Year - min(Year), by = ID]
```

---

In base R, `ave` is probably easiest for adding a groupwise columns to existing data:

```
your_data$Age = with(your_data, ave(Year, ID, function(x) x - min(x)))
```

but the syntax isn't as nice as the options above.

---

You can test on this data:

```
your_data = read.table(text = "  Year ID Age 
1 1975 6  -1   
2 1975 6  -1   
3 1976 6  -1   
4 1977 6  -1   
6 1975 9  -1   
8 1978 9  -1 ", header = T)
```

Comment: I get this error message in return when trying to run library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%               # group by ID
  mutate(Age = Year - min(Year)) # add new column                           
   Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Age` must be length 84 (the group size) or one, not 7664

Comment: Well, it works on the sample data. (You can get that to work, right? Try the data at the bottom of my question.) So what's different about your data? Are the column names spelled the same way? Are you sure `Age` is capitalized? Do you have another object called `Age` in your workspace, that has length 7664?

Comment: And please don't tell me you used `attach`. If so, `detach()` immediately and never use `attach()` again.

Comment: Worked perfectly sorry for the confusion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, what is your aversion to attach()?

Comment: `attach` causes more problems than it solves. It makes it possible for columns to get out of sync with each other, and out of sync with the data frame. I wrote a little bit more [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42284422/903061). Even if you look at the help page `?attach`, the *Good Practice* section essentially says *"`with` is usually better - and don't use it inside functions!"*.

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to figure out the relative age based on one intial birth year, 1975 (which it seems like you are), then you can just make a new column called "RelativeAge" and set it equal to the year - 1975

```
data$RelativeAge = (Year-1975)
```

then just get rid of the original "Age" column, or rename as necessary

Comment: Welcome to the site! OPs example isn't super clear, but I do think they want to do this operation for each ID value in the data frame, which may have different Year values.