# Trouble using attach() in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble assigning columns to the strings above them.  I believe the proper way to do this is use the `attach()` function.  I have a csv file loaded with columns of data on `Flight`, `O.ring`, and `Temp`.  I have tried to clear previously attached data by using the `detach()` function, but have not had any luck.

```
### Files saved in the directory below
setwd("/Users/newUser/desktop/programming")
data <- read.table("Challenger.csv", header=TRUE)
attach(data)
O.ring
Error: object 'O.ring' not found
Flight
Error: object 'Flight' not found
Temp
Error: object 'Temp' not found
fit1 <- glm(O.ring ~ Temp + Pressure, family=binomial(logit))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'O.ring' not found
fit1
Error: object 'fit1' not found
```

Edit:  I also need help accessing the columns stored in data to use them to model.  Any idea what the problem is with my `fit1`?

Comment: With this, how to I use the columns to model my data?  It looks like the only way to access it is like this: str(Flight.Temp.Pressure.O.ring.Number)

Comment: It doesn't look like you read your data in correctly. How is your file structured? read.table assumes it's white space delimited but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `attach()`.  Ever.  Forget it exists.

`glm()` has a `data` argument.  Using that proves much less stressful.

```
glm(O.ring ~ Temp + Pressure, family = binomial(logit), data = data)
```

If you want to know why `attach()` is not advisable, see [Why is it not advisable to use attach() in R and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: Using `attach()` resulted in extra categories being added to my boxplot, which were not present in the data. At first I didn't know the cause. Thanks for this advice.