# Importing dataset from Qualtrics to R

Tags: r, qualtrics

I have generated a dataset from Qualtrics (tried the .sav and .csv options, and manually saving the .csv as .xlsx) and imported it (in the different versions) into R. When I ask R to define the objects in the tbl_df, it displays a long list of objects (including Q9021 below). When I try to get any information about individual objects (using basic commands like "class," "mode," "mean" etc.), I always get an error, e.g.:

> "> class(Q9021) 
>   Error: object 'Q9021' not found"

What might be the problem here? Please help

Comment: Attach a sample of your data please, that would help us help you

But judging from what you're saying I think you're unfamiliar with dataframes and dataframe syntax? Does `tbl_df$Q9021` give you what you want?

Comment: My unfamiliarity with dataframes was indeed the problem. Attaching the dataframe solved the issue. Thank you for your response.

Comment: good to hear. Generally people avoid attaching dataframes, which is why I didn't mention it. This is a nice link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: There might also be some issues when importing the csv into R. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314805/how-to-import-qualtrics-data-in-csv-format-into-r