# Unique length each column in dataframe without NA

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have tbl_df from csv file whit different length of columns, but all dataframe displaying as same length, where no data is NA. For example, in first column data only until row 120, but in second column data until 200, so `dim(df)` is 200, and missing data for first column is `na`.

How I can see real  length of each column? I trying `dim`, `length`, 'nrow' specific for each column but without success its always display max size of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```r
colSums(!is.na(df))
```

Comment: but it did across all df? `for (i in 1:length(train_set)){
 print(colSums(!is.na(train_set[i])))}` -  looks not good

Comment: @TeoK no need for "forloop", !is.na works on full dataframe, returns logical matrix, then colSums, sums for each column.

Comment: I don't know what `train_set` is. If `train_set` is a dataframe, the `for` loop is not needed: 
`colSum(!is.na(df))` returns the length of each column of the dataframe excluding the `NA`

Comment: `train_set` is `df`, my apologies, but in console it's look not well, each column have a very long name, and count of column 40+. Can I do some table/pivot table with dpyr?

Comment: i think it is not necessary to use `pivot_longer`. Maybe just doing `as.data.frame(colSums (!is.na(df)))`

Comment: @TeoK See this [dpyr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50357736/680068) from the linked post.