# How do I refer to multiple columns in a dataframe expression?

Tags: r, dataframe

Writing this is clunky:

```
df$a <- df$b + df$c
```

Is there a way to do (the equivalent of):

```
with df:
    $a <- $b + $c
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `with` command

```
df$a <- with(df, b + c)
```

---

Another option is using `attach`, which however [is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

```
attach(df)
df$a <- b + c
```

---

Another options with `data.table` and `dplyr` as suggested by @SymbolixAU

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, a := b + c]
```

---

If you prefer `dplyr` chains.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(a:= b + c)
```

---

There is also forward pipe operator (`%<>%`) in `magrittr` package which doesn't require you to assign the object again to the variable.

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
  mutate(a = b + c)
```

---

Another one similar to `with` is using `transform` (suggested by @Maurits Evers)

```
df <- transform(df, a = b + c)
```

Comment: perhaps worth showing the `data.table` approach too : `setDT(df)[, c := a + b]` ?

Comment: and `dplyr` : `df %>%
 mutate(c := a + b)`

Comment: Perhaps also mention base R's `df <- transform(df, a = b + c)`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks. Added, should be helpful for future readers.