# Convenient way to delegate function calls

Tags: r, function, function-declaration

I have a series of similar functions that all need to extract some values from a data frame. Something like this:

```
foo_1 <- function(data, ...) {
  x <- data$x
  y <- data$y

  # some preparatory code common to all foo_X functions

  # .. do some boring stuff with x and y

  # pack and process the result into 'ret'
  return(ret)
}
```

These functions are then provided as arguments to some other function (let us call it "the master function". I cannot modify the master function).

However, I wish I could avoid re-writing the same preparatory code in each of these functions. **For example**, I don't want to use `data$x` instead of assigning it to `x` and using `x` because it makes the boring stuff hard to read. Presently, I need to write `x <- data$x` (etc.) in all of the `foo_1`, `foo_2`... functions. Which is annoying and clutters the code. Also, packing and processing is common for all the `foo_N` functions. Other preparatory code includes scaling of variables or regularization of IDs.

What would be an elegant and terse way of doing this?

One possibility is to `attach()` the data frame (or use `with()`, as Hong suggested in the answer below), but I don't know what other variables would then be in my name space: attaching data can mask other variables I use in `fun_1`. Also, preferably the `foo_N` functions should be called with explicit parameters, so it is easier to see what they need and what they are doing.

Next possibility I was thinking of was a construction like this:

```
foo_generator <- function(number) {

  tocall <- switch(1=foo_1, 2=foo_2, 3=foo_3) # etc.

  function(data, ...) {
    x <- data$x
    y <- data$y
    tocall(x, y, ...)
    # process and pack into ret
    return(ret)
}

foo_1 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  # do some boring stuff
}
```

Then I can use `foo_generator(1)` instead of `foo_1` as the argument for the master function.

Is there a better or more elegant way? I feel like I am overlooking something obvious here.

Comment: Can you make a new function for your variable assignment and common code so you don't have to repeat it a bunch of times? Then call that function within your foo_N functions? Or don't put the common stuff in a function and have the common code part in your global environment?

Answer (score 4):

You might be overthinking it. You say that the code dealing with preparation and packing are common to all `foo_n` functions. I assume, then, that `# .. do some boring stuff with x and y` is where each function differs. If that's the case then just create a single `prep_and_pack` function which takes a function name as a parameter, and then pass in `foo_1`, `foo_2`, etc. For example:

```r
prep_and_pack <- function(data, func){
    x <- data$x
    y <- data$y

    # preparatory code here

    xy_output <- func(x, y) # do stuff with x and y

    # code to pack and process into "ret"

    return(ret)
}
```

Now you can create your `foo_n` functions that do different things with `x` and `y`:

```r
foo_1 <- function(x, y) {
    # .. do some boring stuff with x and y
}

foo_2 <- function(x, y) {
    # .. do some boring stuff with x and y
}

foo_3 <- function(x, y) {
    # .. do some boring stuff with x and y
}
```

Finally, you can pass multiple calls to `prep_and_pack` into your master function, where `foo_1` etc. are passed in via the `func` argument:

```r
master_func(prep_and_pack(data = df, func = foo_1),
            prep_and_pack(data = df, func = foo_2),
            prep_and_pack(data = df, func = foo_3)
            )
```

You could also use `switch` in `prep_and_pack` and/or forgo the `foo_n` functions completely in favor of if-else conditionals to deal with the various cases, but I think the above keeps things nice a clean.

Comment: I assigned the bounty because your answer got the most votes; however, none of the presented solutions suit me. For example, since I am passing the  function as an argument to another function, I cannot control how it is called or give it an extra arg.

Comment: Would my solution not still work? You can just call the `foo_n` the way you like, but the preparatory code is all nicely contained in the `prepFun`. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Does it help, if one rewrites `prep_and_pack` as a function generator? I.e. just adding `generator <- function(data, func) function(data, ...) { ...; output <-  func(x,y, ...); ...}`

Comment: @January it's not unusual to pass in extra args for an inner function as an arg (or as args) to the outer function, e.g. `prep_and_pack(data = df, func = foo_1, func_args = list(arg1 = val1, arg2 = val2, ...))`. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "how it is called". Can you describe your issue in more detail?

Comment: I am building a widget factory for ggplot. The functions are the drawing functions which are passed as arguments to the `draw_group` argument of `ggproto`, they are called with standard set of arguments that I cannot influence. Adding a generator helps, that is true, but this is exactly what I have shown in my question.

Comment: In the question, the generator has to know about existence of `func_01`, whereas in the provided answer one may implement new functions `func_x` without touching the generator code, because the function is provided as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The requirements still seem a bit vague to me,
but if your code is so similar that you can simply wrap it around a helper function like `tocall` in your example,
and your input is in a list-like structure
(like a data frame which is just a list of columns),
then just write all your `foo_*` functions to take the "spliced" parameters like in your proposed solution,
and then use `do.call`:

```
foo_1 <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}

foo_2 <- function(x, y) {
  x - y
}

data <- list(x = 1:2, y = 3:4)

do.call(foo_1, data)
# [1] 4 6

do.call(foo_2, data)
# [1] -2 -2
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the following is a good idea. It reminds me a bit of programming with macros. I don't think I would do this. You'd need to carefully document because it is unexpected, confusing and not self-explanatory.

If you want to reuse the same code in different functions, it might be an option to create it as an unevaluated call and evaluate that call in the different functions:

```
prepcode <- quote({
  x <- data$x
  y <- data$y
  }
)

foo_1 <- function(data, ...) {
  eval(prepcode)
  # some preparatory code common to all foo_X functions

  # .. do some boring stuff with x and y

  # pack and process the result into 'ret'
  return(list(x, y))
}

L <- list(x = 1, y = "a")
foo_1(L)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "a"
```

It might be better, to then have `prepcode` as an argument to `foo_1` to make sure there won't be any scoping issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use `with` inside the function:

```r
foo_1 <- function(data, ...) {
  with(data, {
    # .. in here, x and y refer to data$x and data$y
  }
}
```

Comment: This has the same drawback as `attach`. `data` may contain loads of other stuff and I don't control it and I can't remove the other stuff. Consider `adjustment=9 ; with(data, print(adjustment))` when `data$adjustment != NULL`.

Comment: You are _defining_ `foo_1` and you thus control everything that it does, and everything that it needs.

Comment: That general statement is certainly true, but using `with` is one of the ways one can sometimes loose that control by using an environment which is built on data which I don't control , don't you agree? I could, of course, put all the code within the `with()` call, but then (i) it would not be very elegant and (ii) it would add to the things that can go wrong and I need to worry about. Or I could construct `data2` using only what I need and then use `with` on that. But then again I need to repeat boring code in every function. Not to mention the fact that I would prefer to call `foo(x,y)`.

Comment: The solution is to write `foo_1` so that you don't have to worry about clashing variable names. But also, there are clearly requirements that you didn't put into the question. Voting to close as unclear....

Comment: Which requirements would that be? Also, yes, of course the solution *is* to write `foo_1` such that I don't need to worry about clashing variable names, I just say that using `with` is a way of making sure that I *do* need to worry about clashing variable names.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand fully, but can't you simply use a function for all common stuff, and then unpack that into the `foo_N` functions using `list2env`? For example:

```
prepFun <- function(data, ...) {
    x <- data$x
    y <- data$y
    tocall(x, y, ...)
    # process and pack into a named list called ret
    # so you know specifically what the elements of ret are called
    return(ret)
}

foo_1 <- function(data, ...) {

  # Get prepFun to do the prepping, then use list2env to get the result in foo_1
  # You know which are the named elements, so there should be no confusion about
  # what does or does not get masked.
  prepResult <- prepFun(data, ...)
  list2env(prepResult)

  # .. do some boring stuff with x and y

  # pack and process the result into 'ret'
  return(ret)

}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I think defining a function factory for this task is a bit overkill and confusing. You can define a general function and use `purrr::partial()` on it when passing it to your master function.

Something like :

```
foo <- function(data, ..., number, foo_funs) {
  tocall <- foo_funs[[number]])
  with(data[c("x", "y")], tocall(x, y, ...))
    # process and pack into ret
   return(ret)
}

foo_1 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  # do some boring stuff
}

foo_funs <- list(foo_1, foo_2, ...)
```

Then call `master_fun(fun = purrr::partial(foo, number =1) , ...)`

Answer (score 0):

another possibility is to use `list2env` which saves the components of a list in to a specified environment:

```
foo_1 <- function(data){
  list2env(data, envir = environment())
  x + y
}

foo_1(data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 3:4))
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499320/should-attach-be-avoided-in-this-situation).

Comment: How would that help? Assigning local variables was only one of the tasks that need to be done in each and every of the `foo_X` functions.