# Trying to understand the use of attach in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R so please don't blast me.

I've downloaded a dataset file from the web, and i correctly imported it using the `read.table()` function.

```
Auto = read.table("Path")
```

Now, if i run the `ls()` function i correctly see Auto in the user environment.

If i want to accede the dataset's columns as variables, i have to first attach the dataset, using for example the function `attach("Package_path")`.

Is this necessity due to the function `read.table()` which creates a new and separate environment every time we import a dataset ?
What i think is that the dataset's variables are already present after the using of `read.table()` , the only thing is that are not attached to user environment yet...

Comment: DO NOT USE attach, this is a really bad practice, if you want to use a variable from Auto, use something like `Auto$V1`

Comment: Which are the differences from attach ?

Comment: `attach` adds a database (a list, a data.frame like your Auto) to search path, This means that the database is searched when evaluating a variable, so objects in the database can be accessed by simply giving their names.

Comment: I suggest you read [Why is it not advisable to use attach() in R, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead#10067681).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it not advisable to use attach() in R, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead)