# How to "really" convert variables in R

Tags: r

I'm reading ISLR and in the Carseats file, I use:

```
Price <- as.factor(Price)
```

to make the variable Price a Factor for experiment. However, when I put:

```
str(Carseats)
```

it still shows that Price is Num not Factor. Of course when I try:

```
class(Price)
```

it is Factor. So, how do I really change the data type? I.E., how to change the data type in the csv file as well?

Comment: Because you didn't modify the data frame. `Carseats$Price <- factor(Carseats$Price)`

Comment: Have you used `attach(Carseats)`? if so, don't. It's a source for errors of the type you are getting. Don't use `attach()` at all.

Comment: Thanks guys! In this link I saw the issue, it's because of `attach()` as suggested by @RuiBarradas : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead].