# Replicating lattice graph for a mixed model

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, mixed-models

I am trying to replicate a lattice graph using ggplot2 for a mixed model. My ggplot graph looks very similar but I am not sure about about loess line model fitted.

My goal is to add a loess line from the mixed model using ggplot2. Below is an example of my commands :

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(lme4)

data(MathAchieve)
attach(MathAchieve)
mses <- tapply(SES, School, mean) 
mses[as.character(MathAchSchool$School[1:10])] 

Bryk <- as.data.frame(MathAchieve[, c("School", "SES", "MathAch")])

names(Bryk) <- c("school", "ses", "mathach")
sample20 <- sort(sample(7185, 20)) # 20 randomly sampled students

Bryk$meanses <- mses[as.character(Bryk$school)]

Bryk$cses <- Bryk$ses - Bryk$meanses
sector <- MathAchSchool$Sector
names(sector) <- row.names(MathAchSchool)
Bryk$sector <- sector[as.character(Bryk$school)]

attach(Bryk)

cat <- sample(unique(school[sector=="Catholic"]), 20)
Cat.20 <- groupedData(mathach ~ ses | school,  data=Bryk[is.element(school, cat),])
```

Graph with Lattice:

[image: Graph with Lattice]

```
trellis.device(color=T)
xyplot(mathach ~ ses | school, data=Cat.20, main="Catholic", 
       panel=function(x, y) {
         panel.loess(x, y, span=1) 
         panel.xyplot(x, y)
         panel.lmline(x, y, lty=2)
       })
```

Graph with ggplot:

[image: Graph with ggplot]

```
ggplot(Cat.20, aes(x = ses, y =mathach )) + 
  geom_point(size=1, shape=1) + 
  stat_smooth(method="lm",se=F)+
  stat_smooth(, colour="Red",se=F)+
  facet_wrap(school~., scale = "free_y")
```

Please any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preamble**

Before going into the explanation, allow me to refer you to this question: [Why is it not advisable to use attach() in R, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067680/8449629)

While it's recommendable that you made your question reproducible, the code you used can do with some clean-up. For example:

1. Don't include packages that aren't used in the code (I didn't see a need for the `lme4` package);
2. There's no need to use `data(...)` to load `MathAchieve`. See the "Good Practices" section from `?data` for more details.
3. As mentioned above, don't use `attach()`.
4. For complete reproducibility, use `set.seed()` before any random sampling.
5. For a *minimal* example, don't plot 20 schools when a smaller number would do.

Since you are using one of the tidyverse packages for plotting, I recommend another from its collection for data manipulation:

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(dplyr)

Bryk <- MathAchieve %>%
  select(School, SES, MathAch) %>%
  group_by(School) %>%
  mutate(meanses = mean(SES),
         cses = SES - meanses) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(MathAchSchool %>% select(School, Sector),
            by = "School")
colnames(Bryk) <- tolower(colnames(Bryk))

set.seed(123)
cat <- sample(unique(Bryk$school[Bryk$sector == "Catholic"]), 2)
Cat.2 <- groupedData(mathach ~ ses | school,
                     data = Bryk %>% filter(school %in% cat))
```

**Explanation**

Now that that's out of the way, let's look at the relevant functions for `loess`:

from `?panel.loess`:

```
panel.loess(x, y, span = 2/3, degree = 1,
            family = c("symmetric", "gaussian"),
            ... # omitted for space
            )
```

from `?stat_smooth`:

```
stat_smooth(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "smooth",
  method = "auto", formula = y ~ x, span = 0.75, method.args = list(), 
  ... # omitted for space
  )
```

where `method = "auto"` defaults to `loess` from the `stats` package for <1000 observations.

from `?loess`:

```
loess(formula, data, span = 0.75, degree = 2,
      family = c("gaussian", "symmetric"),
      ... #omitted for space
      )
```

In short, a loess plot's default parameters are `span = 2/3, degree = 1, family = "symmetric"` for the `lattice` package, and `span = 0.75, degree = 2, family = "gaussian"` for the `ggplot2` package. **You have to specify matching parameters if you want the resulting plots to match**:

```
xyplot(mathach ~ ses | school, data = Cat.2, main = "Catholic", 
       panel=function(x, y) {
         panel.loess(x, y, span=1, col = "red")  # match ggplot's colours
         panel.xyplot(x, y, col = "black")       # to facilitate comparison
         panel.lmline(x, y, lty=2, col = "blue")
       })

ggplot(Cat.2, aes(x = ses, y = mathach)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 1) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = F)+
  stat_smooth(span = 1,
              method.args = list(degree = 1, family = "symmetric"),
              colour = "red", se = F)+
  facet_wrap(school ~ .) +
  theme_classic() # less cluttered background to facilitate comparison
```

[image: lattice result]

[image: ggplot2 result]