# Subset function to study gender difference in R

Tags: r

I want to study the gender difference and so I am attempting to use the `R` function but I don't know how to use it.

This is my script.

```
data<-read.csv(file.choose())
attach(data)
data
```

## Subset

```
newdata <- subset(data, Gender=="1","2", select=Total)
```

Comment: Hi RiyaShah. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: Do you need `subset(data, Gender %in% 1:2, select=Total)` ?

Comment: A few additional remarks: Try to avoid using `attach` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead) for an explanation. Similarly there are better options for sub-setting data than `subset`, especially if used in functions. In your case `data[data$Gender %in% c("1", "2"), "Total"]` would probably work also.

Comment: Thank you dario. i'll try it for sure!

Answer (score 0):

```
data1 <- data[data$Gender=="1",] # data for gender "1"
data2 <- data[data$Gender=="2",] # data for gender "2"
```

For number of records in different gender:

```
data.gender <- data %>% group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(Count=n())
```

Comment: Thank you jay! I'll try it for sure.