# Why is my train() function not working within a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, machine-learning, r-caret

I am running this code and getting the following error after the for loop:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

The subsequent ggplots are giving straight lines on the fit indices because the train function is not working within the for loop.

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Wage)
library(caret)

#6
#code informed by https://ambarishg.wordpress.com/2015/09/08/caret-and-polynomial-linear-regression/

set.seed(1)

inTraining = createDataPartition(Wage$age, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training = Wage[ inTraining,]
testing = Wage[-inTraining,]

fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  repeats = 10)

set.seed(2)
degree = 1:10
RSquared = rep(0,10)
RMSE = rep(0,10)

for ( d in degree)
{
  LinearRegressor <- train(wage ~ poly(age,d),data=training, method = "lm", trControl = fitControl)
  
  RSquared[d] <- LinearRegressor$results$Rsquared
  
  RMSE[d]<- LinearRegressor$results$RMSE
  
}

library(ggplot2)
Degree.RegParams = data.frame(degree,RSquared,RMSE)
ggplot(aes(x = degree,y = RSquared),data = Degree.RegParams) +
  geom_line()

ggplot(aes(x = degree,y = RMSE),data = Degree.RegParams) +
  geom_line()
```

I think the problem is related to defining the variable d within the for loop. degree is successfully specified as a vector with length 10, but then when d is defined in degree, subsequent input of d into the console results in a vector of length 1.

Code from https://ambarishg.wordpress.com/2015/09/08/caret-and-polynomial-linear-regression/

Comment: I encounter your error also, I don't know the reason but would say that blog post is very old, likely out of date will `caret`. I would say that if you should probably use `tidymodels` instead of `caret`, `tidymodels` is the successor to `caret`. Homepage here: https://www.tidymodels.org/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really a problem. The problem is caused because you attached the dataset Wage. This interferes with the calling of the variables in the train statement. Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead) for more info on attach issues

Solution: start your code as follows and it will run fine.

```
library(ISLR)
library(caret)
data("Wage")

# rest of your code here
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried what you recommended but still got the error message.

Comment: Try in a clean R session and make sure you do not use `attach(Wage)` anywhere.

Comment: I did so and R returned the same error message. I still think there is a problem with the for loop. When I remove the train function from the for loop and specify a polynomial degree, the function works.