# Please missing data

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data

Please, I need some help I am new in R and I am unable to analyze my data. I used this code:

Paises <- read.csv("~/Desktop/UN/Paises.csv")
View(Paises)

````
```{R}
Datos = read.table("~/Desktop/UN/Paises.csv", header=T, sep="," , dec=".") 
str(Datos)
````

Then I do not know how to sum all 2010 or all 2020 I tried with colSums but it was not possible. I want to know the total population in 2010 and also know the total in 2010 from different regions or even different countries

[image]

Comment: Hello daniela, please always provide a minimal reproducible example in terms of code (no screenshots), as that makes it easier for people to help you : )

Comment: Thank you  finnmglas

Comment: The line `install.packages(usingR)` doesn't make sense. Any package name you wish to install needs to be in quotes, and there is no package of that name on CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `attach`. Read [Why is it not advisable to use attach() in R, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Your title and description of problem (`unable to analyse my data`) is very vague. You need to tell what exactly you are trying to do. From your code attempt it seems you are trying to `sum` column `2010`. However, from the screenshot I also see that you have spaces in numbers indicating that your columns is of type character (check `sapply(datos, class)`). We cannot take `sum` of character values so first turn the column values to numeric.

```
Datos[-c(1:2)] <- lapply(Datos[-c(1:2)], as.numeric)
```

Now if you want to sum `X2010` column you can do  :

```
sum_2010 <- sum(Datos$X2010, na.rm = TRUE)
sum_2010
```

and if you want to sum all the numeric columns you can use `colSums` :

```
sum_All <- colSums(Datos[-c(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)
sum_All
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to do it :). Please do you mind telling me what is the code to extract data only from the Region SA in the year 2010?

Comment: `subset(Datos, Regiones == 'SA', select = 'X2010')`

Comment: Appreciated! Thank you