# Is there a way to tell R to assume you're subsetting from a particular dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm writing code which subsets from a dataframe a lot e.g. lots of `dataframe_name$column_name` and it's a pain to read and to write. Is there a way to tell R that I'm referencing `dataframe_name` so that I can just write `column_name` for each instance?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: If you want to avoid `$`, use `with`

Comment: It was surprisingly difficult to find the right terms to search for to find these probably duplicate questions. If they don't cover what you need, let us know the specific issue.

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah, the first one covers it - the answer I was looking for is ```attach```, and ```with``` is nice to know about as well. Thanks!

Comment: @DisgruntledOne - i think it should be the other way around. Use `with` and not `attach`.- several reasons here in the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead