# The plot and boxplot (using package ggplot) give the different results

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I wrote the two codes and it seems they give different results.

I think the code given by plot() is correct.

Can anyone tell why the result given by boxplot() is different from plot() and it seems something wrong with the plot given by boxplot()

BTW, the dataset is from the package MASS in R, which is called Boston

```
install.packages('MASS')
library(MASS)
data_set1<-data(Boston,package='MASS')
attach(Boston)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
boxplot(rad,crim,log='y')
plot(crim~as.factor(rad),log='y')
```

Best,
Mati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that `boxplot` and `plot` are generic functions that behave differently based on what is passed to them. In this case, because you specify a factor as your `x` variable in the plot, it really comes down to comparing

```
boxplot(rad, crim, log='y')
boxplot(crim ~ as.factor(rad),log='y')
```

So you are either passing two different parmeters in the first case, or a formula in the second case. These behave very differently. If you don't use a formula, you just get a box plot for each variable you pass in. You can see what happens if you add other column names

```
boxplot(rad, crim, zn, dis, log='y')
```

There you can see that you just get a separate box plot for each of the variables you pass in. The "1" is the distribution of the `rad` variable for all observations, the "2" is the `crim`, and so on.

When you call

```
boxplot(crim ~ as.factor(rad),log='y')
```

You are getting a box plot for each unique value of `rad`. It's not really possible to add over variables when using the formula syntax.

See the `?boxplot` help page for more details.

Also I should mention it's usually a [bad idea to use `attach()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead). It would be better to the `data=` parameter for functions that support it and `with()` for functions that do not. For example

```
with(Boston, boxplot(crim, rad, log="y"))
boxplot(crim~rad, log="y", data=Boston)
```

Comment: I make perfect sense. Thanks, MrFlick