# Transfer imputed dataset from SAS to R?

Tags: r, sas

Hiii all!
I have 25 imputed datasets from SAS, and I transferred these datasets into R. I am wondering how to let R recognize my imputed datasets and perform the analysis?
Here are some codes I have so far:

```
df<-read.spss("IFS.sav",use.value.label=TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE) #worked 

as.mids(long=df,.imp= "X_Imputation_" , .id="survyid" )#doesn't work, it asked me about original dataset. I don't understand why I need that, and i am not sure how to do it. 

with(data=analysis_final, exp=glm(......#this doesn't work. i am wondering how to perform analysis for each imputed dataset and use summary statistics?
```

Comment: You say SAS but your code indicates it's SPSS. Also, we cannot help without having an understanding of your data.

Comment: i only saw example from spss to sas. So i just converted to sav. What do you mean understanding my data.

Comment: I mean this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please try `haven` package to read in SAS datasets and perform the analysis in R.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```r
attach(df)
```

Or

```
attach(*your data name values)
```

Then you will access your variables and you will be able to run summary statistics.

Like:

```
mean(*variable name)
```

Or any statistics analyses.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rPde-SPDVE&ab_channel=StatisticsGlobe) that might help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead