# Why do you use '$" (the dollar sign) while adding multiple conditions in an R code?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I was doing a course on R and I came across this line of code:

```
onlineta_city_hotels <- filter(hotel_bookings, 
                           (hotel=="City Hotel" & 
                             hotel_bookings$market_segment=="Online TA"))
```

This code did successfully produce the expected result. However, I tried removing the dollar sign and executed a new code:

```
onlineta_city_hotels <- filter(hotel_bookings, 
                           (hotel=="City Hotel" & 
                             market_segment=="Online TA"))
```

This code showed the **same result**. So I wanted to know the need for using a dollar sign in such statements.

Comment: You should *not* use `$` indexing inside `dplyr::filter` (just like you wouldn't use `$` indexing inside base R's `subset`). The first code example is not good R code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the `tidyverse` (and `tidyverse` includes `dplyr`) functions use **Data masking**.  To [quote](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_data_masking.html) from package authors-

> .. provides data masking, which blurs the distinction between two types of variables:

> 1. `env-variables` are "programming" variables and live in an environment. They are usually created with `<-`. Env-variables can be any type of R object.

> 2. `data-variables` are "statistical" variables and live in a data frame. Data-variables live inside data frames, so must be vectors.

Now `filter` function comes from `dplyr` which uses data masking. So `market_segment` variable which live inside `hotel_bookings` can be called directly inside dplyr functions.  This may not be the case always with base R functions.

```
hotel_bookings[hotel_bookings$hotel=="City Hotel" & 
                             hotel_bookings$market_segment=="Online TA", ]
```

The following will not work here

```
hotel_bookings[hotel=="City Hotel" & 
                             market_segment=="Online TA", ]
```

Thus inside all `dplyr` functions, variable names can be called by themselves (without using $).

For further reading/reference please see [this page.](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: I don't think *"attaches the dataset"* or the term "attach" is quite the right term here. `dplyr` does *data masking*, which creates an environment from the `data.frame` and extracts variables from that env (internally using `$`). `attach` is often [mis/abused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead) and is different to what `dplyr` does.