# Subset data within lapply for different columns to produce repeated single arm meta-analysis

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, lapply

I am trying to subset data within lapply for different columns to produce repeated single arm meta-analysis using `metaprop` command for many outcomes in 1 step as I have a giant number of outcomes.

Some outcomes have empty cells, so I need to properly subset data within `lapply`

Here is my data and code:

```
############################### Data sample  #####################################
data<- read.table(text="
studlab Number.of.patients  Procedure   Mortality   Post.op.stroke  
Lee2015 15  SPT 0   0
Wang2019    44  SPT     1
Nachira2018 12  SPT 1   1
Zhang2020   20  SPT 1   1
Lee2017 48  SPT 0   1
Lv2018  10  SPT 0   0
Weiping2018 28  SPT 0   0
Liu2021 60  SPM 0   
Gan2020 56  SPM     
Ye2021  105 SPM 1   1
Takeda2021  12  SPM     
Yin2020 22  SPM     0
Gan2020 28  SPM     
Egberts2019 4   SPM 1   1
Wang2019    80  SPM     0
Fujiwara2017    60  SPM 0   1
Mori2017    7   SPM 0   0
Parker2011  8   SPM 0   1
Zhu2021 19  SPM 0   1", header=T, sep="\t")

############################ Same data with dput command ####################
dput(data)
structure(list(studlab = c("Lee2015", "Wang2019", "Nachira2018", 
"Zhang2020", "Lee2017", "Lv2018", "Weiping2018", "Liu2021", "Gan2020", 
"Ye2021", "Takeda2021", "Yin2020", "Gan2020", "Egberts2019", 
"Wang2019", "Fujiwara2017", "Mori2017", "Parker2011", "Zhu2021"
), Number.of.patients = c(15L, 44L, 12L, 20L, 48L, 10L, 28L, 
60L, 56L, 105L, 12L, 22L, 28L, 4L, 80L, 60L, 7L, 8L, 19L), Procedure = c("SPT", 
"SPT", "SPT", "SPT", "SPT", "SPT", "SPT", "SPM", "SPM", "SPM", 
"SPM", "SPM", "SPM", "SPM", "SPM", "SPM", "SPM", "SPM", "SPM"
), Mortality = c(0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Post.op.stroke = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

############################### Used code  #####################################
library(tidyr); library(ggplot2); library(meta); library(metafor)
lapply(names(data)[4:5], function(columntoplot){
 ## To subset based on the outcome column ## 
  df <-subset( data, data[[columntoplot ]] >=0 )  ## NOT WORKING PROPERLY
  
 mp<-metaprop(columntoplot,Number.of.patients,  data=df, studlab=studlab,  method = "Inverse",method.tau = "DL");mp
  
 mp2<- update (mp, byvar=Procedure);mp2
 pdf(filename = paste0(graphname, ".pdf"), width = 20, height = 20)
 forest (mp );   forest (mp2 )
  dev.off()
  })
#################################################################################
```

Comment: Your sample is in an awkward format and in its current form gives a one-column `data.frame`. Can you please fix this and provide sample data with `dput`.

Comment: PS. There are more issues with your sample data. For example, row 2 (Wang 2019) has only four entries instead of five, row 9 (Gan 2020) has only three entries instead of five. Please provide sample data in a reproducible format.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thx for your time and efforts. I edited my question based on your advice.  row 9 (Gan 2020) has only three entries instead of five as this is a real sample of my data and I will need to subset it to include those with actual events even zero events but not NA. Appreciate your guidance. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. In `metaprop`, the `event` and `n` arguments must be *symbols* (not `character` strings) referring to columns in `data`.
2. As you correctly identified, the `subset` command is syntactically incorrect.
3. The filename argument inside `pdf` is `file =` , not `filename =` .
4. I strongly recommend using a linter to ensure consistent code formatting & indentation. Or at the very least, adopt & stick to a style guide to increase the readability of your code.

As to your question, the following seems to work.

```r
# Variables of interest
vars <- names(data)[4:5]

# Reshape `data` from wide to long for the variables of interest
df <- data %>% pivot_longer(all_of(vars))

# Since the loop is not returning anything and only generates plots, 
# use `purrr::walk` to loop through all variables of interest.
vars %>%
    walk(function(var) {
        # Meta-analysis        
        mp <- metaprop(
            event = value, 
            n = Number.of.patients,
            studlab = studlab,
            data = df %>% filter(name == var, !is.na(value)),
            method = "Inverse",
            method.tau = "DL")
        mp2 <- update(mp, byvar = Procedure)
        
        #Plot
        pdf(file = paste0(var, ".pdf"), width = 20, height = 20)
        forest(mp)
        forest(mp2)
        dev.off()
    })
```

Comment: @Mauritz Evers Thx a lot for your precious input. I tried your code but I got 2 errors from my side (`Error in match.arg(method) : object 'value' not found` which was fixed by using `attach(df)` but I got another error `Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector` although I checked using str(df). Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Upvoted.

Comment: Hi @MohamedRahouma. [Don't use `attach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067680/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-use-attach-in-r-and-what-should-i-use-instead) (I'm not aware of any good use-case for `attach`). The code above works without an error on my side, so there is something else going on on your side. Please restart R from a clean environment. Then try running my code again. Also make sure that you have a recent enough version of R and packages. This is tested & verified on `R_4.1.2`, `metafor_3.4-0`, `metadat_1.2-0`, `tidyverse_1.3.1`.

Comment: @Mauritz Evers Thx a lot. It worked now after I used `tidyverse` and `purrr::walk`. Upvoted and accepted as answer. I would greatly appreciate if you can amend the code to help me getting the results of `mp2` i.e. subgroup analysis in a separate word file or in the same resulting pdf file. Thx again and nice to get in contact with an expert as you.

Comment: Glad it worked Mohamed. I'm definitely no expert with meta-analyses ;-) Not sure what you mean by "getting the results of `mp2`". I simply copied what you had in your original code and assumed that was what you were after.

Comment: @Mauritz Evers Thx a lot. I will try to figure such additional request on my side. Appreciate all your efforts.