# How to calculate confidence bands for fitted values of a linear regression by hand and plot them?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lattice, abline

I'm trying to plot error bands around a linear regression. I'm working with the builtin `trees` dataset in R. Here's my code. No lines are showing up on the plot. Please help!

```
xdev <- log(Volume) - mean(log(Volume))
xdev
ydev <- Girth - mean(Girth)
ydev
b1 <- sum((xdev)*(ydev))/sum(xdev^2)
b0 <- mean(Girth) - mean(log(Volume))*b1
plot(log(Volume) ~ Girth)
abline(coef(lm(log(Volume) ~ Girth)), col=2)
(paste(b0, b1))
y.hat <- b0 + b1*log(Volume)
ss.explained <- sum((y.hat - mean(Girth))^2)
ss.unexplained <- sum((y.hat - Girth)^2)
stderr.b1 <- sqrt((ss.unexplained/29)/sum(xdev^2))
stderr.b1

std.yhat <- sqrt((ss.unexplained/29)*((1/31) + (xdev^2/sum(xdev^2))))
std.yhat
upp <-  y.hat + qt(0.95, 29)*std.yhat
low <-  y.hat - qt(0.95, 29)*std.yhat
upp
low
library(lattice)
plot(log(Volume) ~ Girth, data = trees)
abline(c(b0, b1), lty=1)
points(upp ~ Girth, data=trees, type="l", lty=2)
points(low ~ Girth, data=trees, type="l", lty=2)
```

[image: the graph resulting from this code]

Comment: `abline` is not a lattice function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you want to calculate OLS by hand as well as predictions with confidence bands. Since I'm not familiar with the approach you are using (but you definitely mixed up Y and X in the beginning of your code), I show you how to get the confidence bands with a similar manual approach I'm more familiar with.

```
data(trees)  ## load trees dataset

## fit
X <- cbind(1, trees$Girth)
y <- log(trees$Volume)
beta <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y
y.hat <- as.vector(X %*% beta)

## std. err. y.hat
res <- y - y.hat
n <- nrow(trees); k <- ncol(X)
VCV <- 1/(n - k)*as.vector(t(res) %*% res)*solve(t(X) %*% X)
se.yhat <- sqrt(diag(X %*% VCV %*% t(X)))

## CIs
tcrit <- qt(0.975, n - k)
upp <- y.hat + tcrit*se.yhat
low <- y.hat - tcrit*se.yhat

## plot
with(trees, plot(x=Girth, y=log(Volume)))
abline(a=beta, col=2)
lines(x=trees$Girth, y=upp, lty=2)
lines(x=trees$Girth, y=low, lty=2)
```

[image]

We can compare this with the results of respective R functions, which will give us the same values and, thus, the same plot as above.

```
fit <- lm(log(Volume) ~ Girth, trees)
pred <- stats::predict.lm(fit, se.fit=TRUE, df=fit$df.residual)

with(trees, plot(x=Girth, y=log(Volume)))
abline(fit, col=2)
lines(x=trees$Girth, y=pred$fit + tcrit*pred$se.fit, lty=2)
lines(x=trees$Girth, y=pred$fit - tcrit*pred$se.fit, lty=2)
```

Since you have noted `lattice`, you can further crosscheck using `lattice::xyplot`:

```
lattice::xyplot(fit$fitted.values ~ log(trees$Volume), 
                panel=mosaic::panel.lmbands)
```

[image]

**Note:** It seems you are using `attach`, which is discouraged in the community, see: [Why is it not advisable to use attach() in R, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067680/6574038). I therefore used `with()` and `` `$`() `` instead.